# Fix Python error while launching QGIS 3.28

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, windows

I have installed QGIS 3.28 (Windows 10) and I am getting some errors while launching it.

This error is related to pyplugin_installer :

> An error occurred during execution of following code:
> import pyplugin_installer
>
> traceback.print_exception() failed
>
> Python version:
>
> QGIS version:
> 3.28.8-Firenze 'Firenze', 5ac45272b58
>
> Python path:

I have QGIS 3.18 already installed and it works fine.

I have tried to set PYTHONPATH but I still get the same results.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed after changing the user in QGIS.